# Angular JS with CORS has OPTIONS request pending forever

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, cors

i have been working with angular for a while, and now that i making deploy of two relative big projects, have caught a weird problem. Sometimes the OPTIONS request get stuck in pending forever, blocking the code flow to the next procedure. This happen random, i do login, run around here and there, and then, suddenly the problem appears.

This is the chrome line with the pending request.

[image: Stuck OPTIONS]

Thanks for any collaboration in advance.

-- More Information --

I using Silex on the backend. This call at the screenshot, works sometimes, sometimes doesn't, this is true for all the URLs, they are getting stuck randomly..

Comment: Is your server API actually receiving the OPTIONS request? If it is receiving the request, is it properly replying?

Comment: Yes it is, it reply with the proper headers, the content of response is: "OK" and the status code 200.

Comment: I noticed your example screenshot has a ':' in the url. Do the URLs that work correctly have those too?

Comment: Yep, this is not the problem :) And just for mention, this URL works sometimes, the same URL works and stop working randomly..

Comment: Have you ever figured this out @GuilhermeHenriqueOliveira?

Comment: Actually, after a lot of tries, and a whole morning on Wireshark, seems that what is causing this is the router, or something on the network.

Answer (score 1):

Your OPTIONS response should be a 204 (not 200). Also ensure there's no content in the body of the response.

Comment: Actually there is no RFC specifying which status code should i return, and in a simple search, i saw a lot of reasonable arguments to avoid 204 status without content. This is not the problem...

Comment: @GuilhermeHenriqueOliveira Have you actually tried it though? Sadly just because the spec says something doesn't mean the browsers respect it. I am successfully using a 204 OPTION no content in production. Regardless you'll probably need to provide much more information (like as much header information as possible) if you want to get good answers. Debugging this stuff can be super tricky.

Comment: unfortunately doesn't work.. it still problematic, a lot of OPTIONS requests stucked... i put 204 without content...